# Train Route Planning

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, path-finding

We can model a rail network as a directed graph, where each node is a train station and each edge is a train connecting two train stations. We'll assume that each train travels between its corresponding stations at a regular schedule and takes a fixed amount of time

Your code should take a list of trains, where each train is a tuple `(from, to, base, interval, duration)`, where

1. `from` is an integer denoting the station the train departs from.
2. `to` is an integer denoting the station the train arrives at.
3. `base` is the integer timestamp of an arbitrary departure of the given train.
4. `interval` is a positive integer denoting how often the train departs.
5. `duration` a positive integer denoting how long the train takes.

In other words, the departures are given by `base + n * interval`, and the corresponding arrivals by `base + n * interval + duration`, for integer `n`.
For example, `0 2 -3 4 5` would describe a train going from station `0` to station `2`, which is at station `0` at times `..., -11, -7, -3, 1, 5, 9, 13, ...` and is at station `2` at times `..., -6, -2, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, ...`.

If you are at some station `x` want to take a train from `x` to `y`, you must wait until the train from `x` to `y` is at station `x`. Then, after another `duration` units of time, you are at station `y`.
For example, if at time `0` you're at station `0` and want to use the train described above, you'd need to wait until time `1`, then at time `6` you would be at station `2`.

Given these trains, your code should calculate the earliest arrival time at station `1`, given that you start at station `0` at time `0`. If no route is possible, you should return a distinguished value.

### Worked Example

Suppose we are given input:

```
0 2 -3 4 5
2 1 9 3 2
0 1 -1 7 9
```

From this, we can see the pairs of arrival and departure times of each train are:

```
..., (1, 6), (5, 10), (9, 14), (13, 18), (17, 22), (21, 26), (25, 30), ... 
..., (0, 2), (3, 5), (6, 8), (9, 11), (12, 14), (15, 17), (18, 20), ...
..., (6, 15), (13, 22), (20, 29), (27, 36), (34, 43), (41, 50), (48, 57), ...
```

There are 2 routes from stations `0` to `1`: `0 -> 1` and `0 -> 2 -> 1`.

- For the route `0 -> 1`, we can board the train at time `6` and get off at time `15`.
- For the route `0 -> 2 -> 1`, we can get on train `0 -> 2` at time `1`, arrive at station `2` at time `6`, then immediately board train `2 -> 1`, arriving at station `1` at time `8`.

Out of these, `0 -> 2 -> 1` is the fastest, so we output `8`.

Comment: This looks really interesting, but some worked examples and some test cases would help.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify whether the routes can include cycles (at least one train going from A to B and another train going from B to A). Apart from that, the task seems pretty clear to me. But test cases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are floating point inaccuracies allowed? (a mathematically correct solution, which might fail in practice for big values due to floating-point inaccuracies)

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, that should be fine. It's similar to integer overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 44 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æʒø2£ø˜Á2ôćRJs€ËP*}ε0svy¦¦`U©%∞<®*+Dr@ÏнX+]ß
```

Outputs an empty string if no valid route can be found.

What a mess.. Those arbitrary `base`-times are pretty annoying to deal with.
Ah well, it works.. Will try to golf it some more later on.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9vc2FiaWX//8OmypLDuDLCo8O4y5zDgTLDtMSHUkpz4oKsw4tQKn3OtTBzdnnCpsKmYFXCqSXiiJ48wq4qK0RyQMOP0L1YK13Dn///W1swLDIsLTMsNCw1XSxbMiwxLDksMywyXSxbMCwxLC0xLDcsOV1d) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXS/8PLTk06vMPo0OLDO07POdxodHjLkfYgr@JHTWsOdwdo1Z7balBcVnlo2aFlCaGHVqo@6phnc2idlrZLkcPh/gt7I7RjD8//r6QXpvM/OjraQMdIR9dYx0THNFYn2kjHUMdSx1jHCMg2ALJ1DXXMdSxjY3UUorHwjXQMdEx1jKH6THQMDXRM0OViYwE).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Get all valid routes:

```python
æ                # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-list of quintuplets
 ʒ               # Filter it by:
  ø              #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
   2£            #  Keep the first two inner lists
     ø           #  Zip/transpose back
                 #  (we now have a list of all [from,to]-pairs for the current potential
                 #  route)
      ˜          #  Flatten it
       Á         #  Rotate it once towards the left
        2ô       #  Split it back into pairs
  ć              #  Extract the head
   R             #  Reverse it
    J            #  Join it together to a string
                 #  (note: only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, including "01")
  s              #  Swap so the remainder-list is at the top
   €Ë            #  Check for each pair whether they're equal
     P           #  Check if this is truthy for all of them
  *              #  Check if both are truthy
 }               # Close the filter
```

[Try just the first step online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJTkw7vMDq0@PCO03MONxod3nKkPcir@FHTmsPdAVq1//9HRxvoGOnoGuuY6JjG6kQb6RjqWOoY6xgB2QZAtq6hjrmOZWwsAA)

Step 2: Calculate the time each route takes, and leave the smallest as result:

```python
ε                # Map over each valid route:
 0               #  Start at time 0 (let's call this the `current_time`)
  s              #  Swap so the route-list is at the top of the stack
   vy            #  For-each over its quintuplets:
     ¦¦          #   Remove the `from` and `to` from the quintuplet
     `           #   Pop and push the remaining three values to the stack
      U          #   Pop the top one (`duration`), and store it in variable `X`
      ©          #   Store the next top (`interval`) in variable `®` (without popping)
       %         #   Pop both values, and calculate base modulo interval
     ∞<          #   Push an infinite non-negative list: [0,1,2,...]
       ®*        #   Multiply each by interval `®`: [0,interval,2*interval,...]
         +       #   Add the (base modulo interval) to each
          D      #   Duplicate the infinite list
           r     #   Reverse the values on the stack
            @    #   Check for each value in the infinite list if it's >= `current_time`
             Ï   #   Only keep the values in the infinite list at the truthy indices
              н  #   Pop and push the first/lowest
     X+          #   Add duration `X` to it,
                 #   which is the next iteration's `current_time`
]                # Close both the loop and map
 ß               # Pop and push the minimum
                 # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes

Expects an array of tuples `[ from, to, base, interval, duration ]`. Returns \$+\infty\$ if there's no solution.

```javascript
f=(a,p,t=0,m)=>p^1?Math.min(...a.map(([A,B,b,i,d])=>p^A|m>>B&1?1/0:f(a,B,t+((b-t)%i+i)%i+d,m|1<<B))):t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczNDoIwEATgu0@xF00bhkpRYyACgbtPQDApf1pjgUjjiXdHJPGwc/hmsk/1UWP11oN1u75u5rmNmMIAG3kwPIqHm0yuyj6E0R0TQihh1MBYniJDCY26WEfpZOI428lE7r2wXT5ksA5jpWv5Vjv6FzXMJC@XjHMe2rnqu7F/NeLV31nL8g1RTh7IB7kH0BF0ogKrLiRBFICWwv@rt6q73BkUULEpOJ@/)

Or [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##NctBDoIwEAXQPaeYjck0TGtBjYEECew9AalJEdAaoI00Xr8iiYv5i/f/vPRHL/e3cZ7PtutDGArU5MgXkhUXd0vKq/ZPMZkZhRBaTNohNhXV1JKhTm2jqkz2Mh/Wx5p8jNhyz3YmNr/oGGO5D3c7L3bsxWgfOGATATQgCVICfiA4EpxA0aYrJQSQEaxF@le5KV/vTJCBihRj4Qs) if the graph is guaranteed to be acyclic.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                       // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,                        //   a[] = list of routes
  p,                        //   p = current position
  t = 0,                    //   t = current time
  m                         //   m = mask of visited stations
) =>                        //
p ^ 1 ?                     // if the current position is not 1:
  Math.min(...              //   take the minimum of ...
    a.map(                  //     for each route in a[] going from
    ([A, B, b, i, d]) =>    //     A to B with parameters (b, i, d):
      p ^ A |               //       if the current position is not A
      m >> B & 1 ?          //       or B was already visited:
        1 / 0               //         return +Infinity
      :                     //       else:
        f(                  //         do a recursive call:
          a,                //           pass a[] unchanged
          B,                //           set p = B
          t +               //           compute the updated time
          ((b - t) % i + i) //           by adding the delay before
          % i               //           departure
          + d,              //           and the duration
          m | 1 << B        //           mark B as visited
        )                   //         end of recursive call
    )                       //     end of map()
  )                         //   end of Math.min()
:                           // else:
  t                         //   destination reached: return t
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: even if the graph can be cyclic, in what scenario would it ever be shorter to cycle over non-cycle? If there is a cycle, you can just wait at that station, preventing the cycle. Or am I missing something? (e.g. if cycle `0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1` is shorter than `0 -> 1`, that first one can also just be `0 -> 2 -> 3 -> wait -> 1`)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Cycles are never worth considering for the best path. But if there are cycles, we need some extra code to prevent infinite recursion. (There may be a shorter way than my current solution, though.)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 111 bytes:

```py
f=lambda t,s=0,D=0:min(m)if(m:=[D]*(s==1)+[K for a,b,c,d,e in t if a==s and(K:=f(t,b,max(c%d-D,0)+D+e))])else[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwDEDvfkUuQusy6DZFHeS2m59QeqhuxcJax9aDfv2MXlQUDwnkJXnJcEvnS6x2wzjPjnobjq2FhBMpbEjVwUcRpHci1KQbsxITUSEzfQB3GcHiEU/YYgc@QgLvwBJNYGMrDjU5kbgf7FWclm3eoJJZk3VSGtn1U6fNPIw@JuGE1gqhRMgrhDXCxiBoLguEPQKz8gHUE@QcW@bGSLn42P/bZBvnDdtebr5UMFz/nH5/5Vs@3wE)

Comment: `[1,0][D>c]` => `(D<c)`

Comment: `[[0, 2, 0, 5, 3], [2, 1, 4, 10, 4]]` results in 11 instead of 8 (expected route: 0->2 in 3 minutes; wait 1 minute; 2->1 in 4 minutes).

Comment: Errors for `[[1, 0, -3, 4, 5], [0, 1, -1, 7, 9]]` (expected 15)

Comment: @Jitse The OP makes no mention of cycles.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 119 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,n=0,t=0:t*(n==1)or min([f(a-{(x,y,s,i,d)},y,s-(s-t)//i*i+d)for x,y,s,i,d in a if x==n]or[max(sum(a,()))**2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBCoMwEIXhvaeY5YydYKItpYWcRFykSGigiaIpKOLZbSylXXT35uOffo73LlTbZvXD@FtrwHDQkqOW15hj0FpRN4B3AWuLRiw48cwjO25p3ZfAUUQqCpe7Q0s2td8AXAADzsKkdWi6ofZmwvHp0TASUZ6XDW394EJEi0uGkqFkEBXDkeFEnGE6Ewol5c/SrP4qxXB5e/lJ1P7GcE6eZCXaXg)